# Samsung S6 can't transfer files to Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, files, android, samsung, transfer

My laptop only shows Samsung Android, but won't display any files on my phone.  it used to work fine when I was Ubuntu 14 before I upgraded to 16.04.

I have android 6.0.1

Comment: do you unlock your device?

Comment: Yes, unlocked, I followed all old posts on this, but nothing worked for me.

Comment: I have the identical setup (Ubuntu 16.04, Samsung S6 running Android 6.0.1) and I just hook them together with USB cable. Works great. My phone is not rooted.

Comment: have you tried reinstalling mtp drivers?